# Spring data mongo fails to parse correct aggregate pipeline from string

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to run the following mongo aggregate pipeline in Spring

```
db.project.aggregate([ 
    {
      $match: {$and: [ {"itemId": "30022"}, {"enterpriseId" : "sk:30000"} ]}
    },
    {
      $lookup:
      {
      from: "card_types",
      let: { ownerId: "$enterpriseId"},
      pipeline: [
         { $match:
            { $expr:
               { $eq: [ "$enterpriseId", "$$ownerId" ] }
            }
         },
         { 
            $project:
               {
                  _id: 0,
                  cardFields: 0
               }
         }
      ],
      as: "cardTypes"
      }
}])
```

it goes through fine on mongo console and gives me the expected results. But when I run the query via `Aggregation` class in Spring it fails with the error

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 4570 (Location4570): 'arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { ownerId: "$enterpriseId" } is type object' on server localhost:11911. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { ownerId: \"$enterpriseId\" } is type object", "code": 4570, "codeName": "Location4570"}
```

Here's the ways I have tried

```
public Flux<Document> getProjectDetails(String enterpriseId, String projectId) {
    List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
    pipeline.add(match(where(accountIdKeyName).is(enterpriseId).and(ownerIdKeyName).is(projectId)));
    Document matchOp = new Document("$match", new Document("$expr", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$enterpriseId", "$$ownerId"))));
    Map<String, Object> projectedFields = new HashMap<>();
    projectedFields.put("_id", "0");
    projectedFields.put("cardFields", "0");
    Document projectOp = new Document("$project", new Document(projectedFields));
    pipeline.add(context ->
            new Document("$lookup", new Document("from", "card_types")
                    .append("let", new Document("ownerId", "$enterpriseId"))
                    .append("pipeline", Arrays.asList(matchOp, projectOp))
                    .append("as", "cardTypes")
            ));
    return mongoOperations.aggregate(newAggregation(pipeline), "project", Document.class);
}
```

and also

```
private final String projectCardTypesLookupQuery = """
        {
           $lookup:
              {
              from: "card_types",
              let: { "ownerId": "$enterpriseId"},
              pipeline: [
                 { $match:
                    { $expr:
                       { $eq: [ "$enterpriseId", "$$ownerId" ] }
                    }
                 },
                 {
                    $project:
                       {
                          _id: 0,
                          cardFields: 0
                       }
                 }
              ],
              as: "cardTypes"
              }
        }
        """;

public Flux<Document> getProjectDetails(String enterpriseId, String projectId) {
    List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
    pipeline.add(match(where(accountIdKeyName).is(enterpriseId).and(ownerIdKeyName).is(projectId)));
    pipeline.add(context -> Document.parse(projectCardTypesLookupQuery));
    return mongoOperations.aggregate(newAggregation(pipeline), "project", Document.class);
}
```

Comment: Share please your spring-boot version. Seems your MongoDB driver is older than `v3.6`

Comment: Spring boot `2.5.5`

Comment: is your MongoDB running `localhost:11911`? Don't you have 2 mongod instances? Seems like 1 of them has `v3.4` (Spring-Boot tries to run there) and second more recent version (where you connect via shell). Share please how do you run in the shell command (screenshot) and make sure you connect to the same instance

Comment: I'm passing mongo host and port via `@TestPropertySource` always use custom ports in tests; so pretty sure multiple instances is not an issue, in either cases it is the same mongo instance, running in kube cluster, while running tests I start kube port fooward on `localhost:11911` to the same mongo instance

Comment: Can you verify the version please? [Getting version of Mongo Instance with Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274805/getting-version-of-mongo-instance-with-java-driver)

Comment: It was a problem with the embedded mongo I was using, configured tests to use a mongo docker container instead and the tests work fine now.